# Read GnuPlot output into image in C#

Tags: c#, image, stream, png, gnuplot

I am using GnuPlot from a C# application. I'd like to read the GnuPlot PNG output directly from Standard Output rather than saving to a file and then reading it. My code looks like this right now:

```
string Path = @"C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe";
Process GnuplotProcess = new Process();
GnuplotProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path;
GnuplotProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
GnuplotProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
GnuplotProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
GnuplotProcess.Start();
StreamWriter SW = GnuplotProcess.StandardInput;
StreamReader SR = GnuplotProcess.StandardOutput;
SW.WriteLine("set terminal pngcairo size 300,200");
foreach (LoadCaseOutput LCO in LoadCases)
{
    foreach (LoadCaseOutput.MemberOutput MO in LCO.Members)
    {
        SW.WriteLine("plot " + MO.GenerateAFEquation(P));
        MO.AFImage = Image.FromStream(SR.BaseStream);
    }
}
SW.WriteLine("exit");
GnuplotProcess.Close();
```

Right now this seems to stall at the Image.FromStream() line. What's going wrong?

Comment: Im guessing GnuPlot StandardOutput isnt actually outputting an image.  What happens if you redirect SR.BaseStream to file.  Can you view it as an image?  According to MSDN, the implied msg is that StandardOutput is text.

Comment: If it is stall is because the end of file is not being signaled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update** (I have updated my code to reflect my comment below)

It appears the problem is when the "exit" command is sent to gnuPlot.  Without the exit command sent to gnuPlot, the program waits.

I took your example and was able to get the program to complete by moving the gnuPlot exit command up in the execution tree.

```
        string Path = @"z:\tools\gnuplot\bin\gnuplot.exe";
        Process GnuplotProcess = new Process();
        GnuplotProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path;
        GnuplotProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        GnuplotProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        GnuplotProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        GnuplotProcess.Start();
        StreamWriter SW = GnuplotProcess.StandardInput;
        StreamReader SR = GnuplotProcess.StandardOutput;
        SW.WriteLine("set terminal pngcairo size 300,200");
        SW.WriteLine("plot f(x) = sin(x*a), a = .2, f(x), a = .4, f(x)");
        SW.WriteLine("exit");

        Image png = Image.FromStream(SR.BaseStream);
        png.Save(@"z:\tools\try3a.png");

        GnuplotProcess.Close();
```

This did correctly generate a PNG file.   For testing, I did try reading from the stream before sending the exit command.  The program waits on the FromStream call.

Matt

Comment: OK, well I didn't want to exit GnuPlot because it takes a second to start up and I want to repeat this over a bunch of equations. As far as what I'm expecting, when I run GnuPlot with the settings which are hard coded in my code above, I get a PNG image directly to the standard output (It's a big string of ASCII but it starts with PNG so I'm assuming it's a valid PNG image). And I get that output on the console **before** I type the exit command

Comment: I fixed my program and I did get StandardOutput (I see I missed one line from your code).  However, I still stand by the exit command placement.  I needed it before I tried reading StandardOutput, or it would hang.  However, the result was not a PNG that I could load in any of my imageviewers.  Not sure what is up with that.  (Again it could be my code not correctly saving the output)

Comment: After playing with my code a bit more, I was able to save the stream to png file, which did display correctly.  Just for testing, I moved the exit to after trying to read the stream, and my program hangs.  It really does seem like you need that exit command before you read the stream.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like the **exit** is necessary then!

Comment: you might do without the exit by writing your own procedure to read the output stream. you need to exit when you reach the end of a png frame, not wait for an eof..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the reading otherwise you would be getting an exception, replace the reading bit with this:

```
Image.FromStream(oFileStream, false, true)
```

It will validate the image as soon as it receives the first bytes and you go from there.